# Eclipse not saving SVN password

Tags: linux, eclipse, svn

I have faced various problem with Eclipse not saving SVN password, or saving password in one workspace and not the other.

I am using openSuse 13.2, but have faced same issue with previous Linux versions.

Facing a "GNOME Keyring" issue I think I found the solution ([credit](https://askubuntu.com/questions/206604/svn-and-gnome-keyring))to my password issue. See my answer below.

Answer (score 1):

I fixed it by editing the file `~/.subversion/config` with `vi`, `gedit` or `nano` , and add the following

```
[auth] 
  password-stores = kwallet
```

On my openSuse 13.2, password-stores was not configured, but comments in config file states:

```
### Set password stores used by Subversion. They should be
### delimited by spaces or commas. The order of values determines
### the order in which password stores are used.
### Valid password stores:
###   gnome-keyring        (Unix-like systems)
###   kwallet              (Unix-like systems)
###   keychain             (Mac OS X)
###   windows-cryptoapi    (Windows)
```

Since I use KDE, I did set it to `kwallet,` and problem is solved, including for workspaces where previousely it was not saving the password.

Answer (score 0):

You may be running eclipse with insufficient authorization.  I run eclipse "As Administrator" on my laptop, and that solved always getting prompted for the same SVN password during commits.   Or if possible, add administrator privilege to your host login, which is why I do not need to run eclipse As Admin on my desktop.